# SQL Azure Query Performance - Terribly Slow Even With Tuned Queries

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

Here's a basic query that relies on two non-clustered indexes:

```
SELECT cc.categoryid, count(*) from company c
INNER JOIN companycategory cc on cc.companyid = c.id
WHERE c.placeid like 'ca_%'
GROUP BY cc.categoryid order by count(*) desc
```

When the exact same database is hosted on SQL Server 2008, on virtually any hardware, this returns < 500 ms. Even with the cache buffers cleared:

```
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE
DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS
```

... this still returns in ~1 second on traditional SQL.

On Azure, it takes approximately 3.5 seconds to return each time.

Some [articles](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2010/01/sql-azure-frequently-asked-questions/) out there seem to suggest that people are generally happy with query performance in **SQL Azure**. And yet here's a basic scenario where 'obvious' tuning has been exhausted and there's no network latency issues to speak of. It's just *really* slow when working w/ large tables (companycategroy has 1.2M records, places has 7.5K).

The total database size is no more than 4GB. Selecting 'Web' edition vs. 'Enterprise' edition doesn't seem to make much of a difference either.

What am I missing?

This is only a basic example, it only gets worse with more sophisticated queries, all of have been [reviewed](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlazure/archive/2010/07/27/10043069.aspx), tuned, and perform well on-premise.

Here's the execution plan:

```
  |--Sort(ORDER BY:([Expr1004] DESC))
       |--Compute Scalar(DEFINE:([Expr1004]=CONVERT_IMPLICIT(int,[Expr1007],0)))
            |--Hash Match(Aggregate, HASH:([cc].[CategoryId]), RESIDUAL:([XX].[dbo].[CompanyCategory].[CategoryId] as [cc].[CategoryId] = [XX].[dbo].[CompanyCategory].[CategoryId] as [cc].[CategoryId]) DEFINE:([Expr1007]=COUNT(*)))
                 |--Hash Match(Inner Join, HASH:([c].[Id])=([cc].[CompanyId]))
                      |--Index Scan(OBJECT:([XX].[dbo].[Company].[IX_Company_PlaceId] AS [c]),  WHERE:([XX].[dbo].[Company].[PlaceId] as [c].[PlaceId] like N'ca_%'))
                      |--Index Scan(OBJECT:([XX].[dbo].[CompanyCategory].[IX_CompanyCategory_CompanyId] AS [cc]))
```

And here are the stats:

```
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 0 ms.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 14 ms, elapsed time = 14 ms.

(789 row(s) affected)

Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'CompanyCategory'. Scan count 1, logical reads 5183, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Company'. Scan count 1, logical reads 8710, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

(1 row(s) affected)

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 3328 ms,  elapsed time = 3299 ms.
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 0 ms.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.
```

Index definitions are as follows:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Company_PlaceId] ON [dbo].[Company] 
(
    [PlaceId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON)
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_CompanyCategory_CompanyId] ON [dbo].[CompanyCategory] 
(
    [CompanyId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON)
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Company] ADD  CONSTRAINT [PK_Company_Id] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON)
GO
```

Comment: Could you please post the text query plan and statistics for the query on `Azure`? Please run `SET STATISTICS IO ON SET STATISTICS TIME ON GO SET SHOWPLAN_TEXT ON GO SELECT …`

Comment: We could certainly do with seeing a query plan...

Comment: We have the execution plan on Azure. We should see the same for his local DB that runs so fast.

Comment: @todda.speot.is, I believe Azure has auto-stats by default. Company.Id is an integer (surrogate key) and Place.Id is a varchar(50) natural key.

Comment: Try hinting something other than a hash match for the join. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173815.aspx

Comment: Any improvement to be made by making IX_Company_PlaceId a covered index on PlaceId, Id?

Comment: @Steve: we don't see a clustered seek here. If `id` is a clustered `PK`, it is implicitly included by any other index.

Comment: Those index definitions are presumably your on-premise ones. SQL Azure doesn't support all of those options and would barf at that script. Did you push your on-premise DB to Azure using the Migration Wizard?

Comment: @Steve, yes pushed using the Migration Wizard. Those definitions were generated in Management Studio connected to Azure db using 'Script Index As' -> 'CREATE TO'.

Comment: The SQLAzure admin portal has a very cool query plan visualization feature. Have you tried that yet? May at least point you to the costlier aspects of your query.

Comment: In my experience Sql Azure basic/web is simply very slow. Why? Shared resources, shared cpu, low RAM, slow disk IO etc. I use both Azure Sql and Sql Server on Azure VM and even that with 8 cores and 56 GB ram is pretty slow due to low disk IO throughput compared to say your development machine which probably have SSD disk or a idle harddrive.

Comment: It's just slow... I've noticed and SQL Azure to cost 4 to 5 times more compared to on-prem for the same level of performance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They seem to use one `CPU` core for your query while on your machine the query probably parallelizes (all operations used by the query do parallelize).

However, an index scan is used for the `LIKE` predicate for some reason while an index seek could suffice.

Please try using this explicit condition instead of `LIKE`:

```
c.placeid >= 'ca'
AND c.placeid < 'cb'
```

and see if it changes the plan to an `Index Seek` on `IX_CompanyPlaceId`.

Comment: Thanks just tried this but it's still producing an Index Scan.

Comment: @Nariman: please run `SELECT COUNT(*), SUM(CASE WHEN placeid LIKE 'ca%' THEN 1 END) FROM company`

Comment: That's probably it. At the moment, those counts match as all companies are rooted at the same country (won't always be the case). However, even when I qualify it to a district/state (i.e. like 'ca_on%', representing 30% of the 1.2M records), I still see delay on Azure, though not not as large. I do see the query parallelizes locally and not on Azure, as you suggested.

Comment: @Nariman: just in case: `_` is a wildcard in `LIKE` conditions, use `LIKE 'ca[_]%'` to match a literal underscore. `Index scan`, however, it really a strange thing here: if the index is used anyway, there is absolutely no reason not to seek it. Could you please post the index definitions?

Comment: Posted the index definitions. With all changes applied (using [_], merge join, using LIKE 'ca_on%' to only match 30% of 1.2M records), on-premise with cache buffers cleared still beats SQL Azure by at least 2X.

Comment: Using 'ca[_]on%' does trigger an index seek, it's only 'ca[_]%' that uses a scan (might have to do w/ the fact that all current records have that prefix). Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Just a few things:

- Are stats up to date on Azure? I'm a bit wary of that Hash Match for a 1.2M row table
- Does Azure have auto stats? If not, your local database might have a lot more information that SQL Azure can't use to pick an optimal query plan
- Index `c.placeid` for some statistics on it
- Why is `c.placeid` a string? Does this follow through to `companyid` and `c.id`? I think this is why you have the Hash Match - try joining on integer surrogate keys instead.

Comment: Thanks. The merge join lowered it by a full second to 2.3 seconds, much better but still not comparable to on-prem.

Answer (score 0):

I am posting this link on Azure SQL Database index maintenance since index maintenance still needs a helping hand.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azuresqldbsupport/2016/07/03/how-to-maintain-azure-sql-indexes-and-statistics/

We use a  runbook  to execute across our 350+ databases on different elastic pools to perform the index maintenance.  Hope others find the information as helpful as we did.